# Грамматическое настоящее и будущее время в русском

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

В русском языке есть грамматическое настоящее и будущее время? Ведь у этих времен нет грамматического показателя. Но вот цитата из русской грамматики -80. **Формы наст. вр. и будущего простого не имеют в своем составе специального показателя времени: роль показателя времени выполняет вся система окончаний со знач. лица и числа, присоединяемых к основе наст. вр. глаголов несов. и сов. вида.**

Answer (score 2):

Времена *есть*, но нет показателей, отвечающих *отдельно* за время глагола. Время определяется по показателям (суффиксы и окончания) *лица и числа*, которые различаются для разных времён. Например, для глагола "зашивать" показатель простого будущего ("зашьют") или настоящего ("зашивают") времени *совмещён* с показателями множественного числа третьего лица.

Для сравнения, в некоторых языках *есть* отдельные показатели времени. Возьмём фразу на суахили: *tutaondoka kesho* ("завтра мы уедем"). В глаголе *tutaondoka* два *отдельных* префикса: *tu* указывает на первое лицо во множественном числе, а *ta* - на будущее время.